# NextJs/TS ESM module import issue

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-forest-pghpk?file=/src/lib/index.ts)

I am migrating some code to NextJS 11 / Webpack 5 and also some modules which are now esm only (the whole remark/unified ecosystem).

Before the upgrade I was able to export all files as a summary in an `index.ts` in the folder such as:

```
export { default as MarkdownRenderer } from './markdownRenderer'
```

And in parent folder sal "lib" (assuming the above is in a folder called `elements`);

```
export * from './elements'
```

Then in my code I can do:

```
import { MarkdownRenderer } from '../lib'
```

This no longer works and breaks with:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

After some experimentation I see that I cannot import/export the element summary index - I have to add all components/files directly in the lib index as:

```
// Not workie
//export * from './elements'

// Workie
export { default as MarkdownRenderer } from './elements/markdownRenderer'
```

I have enabled the esm flag for NextJS and also experimented with `next-transpile-modules` but no luck.

In above sandbox, look at the `src/lib/index.ts` and change the comments to see it work/not work.

How do I keep the ability to manage my summary files on a per folder basis?  I think this is a webpack issue but not totally certain. Typescript certainly does not complain either way during development.

Note that it seems to work with older Node (whatever the default was on CodeSanbox - maybe 10) but on 14/16 its a no go.

Comment: This is super strange; I don't know if it's maybe because of CodeSandbox but I forked your example, tried `import * as ns from '../lib';`, did `console.log(ns);`, then `console.log(ns.MarkdownRenderer)`, then changed the import back to the old one and it started working (although I also changed the default export to a named default export, but that by itself did not fix anything). Might be worth considering reporting it Vercel because it looks like a bug too me.

Comment: Well the bug occurs locally for me. I must add that you need node 14+ - I think it works on older ones. I will add that as a note to my post.

Comment: @paolostyle indeed a bug or missing feature. Posted on NextJs and found a workarund.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution for now is to adjust the NextJS webpack config:

```
config.optimization.providedExports = true
```

[Answer](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/29361#issuecomment-932784386) kindly provided by the webpack author.